# hook_load vs. hook_node_load?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

Can someone explain clearly the difference between [`hook_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_load/7.x) and [`hook_node_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7.x)? `hook_load` says it is a "node-type-specific hook". What does that mean? `hook_node_load` actually has a types parameter.

Comment: One big note is that it is called last. As for definition I'm not sure I can do better than the linked page does under the `$types` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This paragraph in [`hook_node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7.x) docs page explains it in details:

> This hook is invoked during node loading, which is handled by entity_load(), via classes NodeController and DrupalDefaultEntityController. After the node information is read from the database or the entity cache, hook_load() is invoked on the node's content type module, then field_attach_load_revision() or field_attach_load() is called, then hook_entity_load() is invoked on all implementing modules, and finally hook_node_load() is invoked on all implementing modules.

Here's the breakdown, from first to last call:

1. `entity_load()`
2. `hook_load()`
3. `field_attach_load_revision()` or `field_attach_load()`
4. `hook_entity_load()`
5. `hook_node_load()`

What this means to you is that using a different hook you will be able to modify values earlier or later. This matters if you're overriding value from another module for example. Otherwise, I think it's safe to use either.

Comment: In all of my Drupal work, I don't think I have ever used `hook_load()`; always the entity version (when I have one that works on multiple entity types) or the entity specific version (which is probably about 95% of the time).

Comment: Thanks @MPD, same here. I've always used `hook_node_load()` instead.

Comment: @MPD We only implement `hook_node_load()` because `hook_load()` is invoked only for modules implementing a content type.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code of [`NodeController::attachLoad()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/NodeController%3A%3AattachLoad/7.x), and a note in the documentation for [`hook_node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7.x), I would say that `hook_load()` is only invoked for the modules implementing a content type.  In fact, the note in `hook_node_load()` documentation says the following. (Emphasis is mine.)

> **[`hook_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_load/7.x) is invoked on the node's content type module**, then [`field_attach_load_revision()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load_revision/7.x) or [`field_attach_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7.x) is called, then [`hook_entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_load/7.x) is invoked on all implementing modules, and finally [`hook_node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7.x) is invoked on all implementing modules.

Plus, the only code dealing with `hook_load()` implementations is the following one.

```
  // Call object type specific callbacks on each typed array of nodes.
  foreach ($typed_nodes as $node_type => $nodes_of_type) {
    if (node_hook($node_type, 'load')) {
      $function = node_type_get_base($node_type) . '_load';
      $function($nodes_of_type);
    }
  }
```

[`node_type_get_base()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_base/7.x) returns the node type base, which the function documentation describes as follows:

> The base indicates which module implements this node type and is used to execute node-type-specific hooks.

It seems that in the Drupal 7 documentation, the term *node-type-specific* replaced what in the Drupal 6 documentation was described as *used by node modules*. See [Drupal 6 `hook_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21node.php/function/hook_load/6.x), [Drupal 7 `hook_validate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_validate/7.x), and [Drupal 6 `hook_validate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21node.php/function/hook_validate/6.x).

To be sure that is the only code invoking `hook_load()`, see [`DrupalDefaultEntityController::attachLoad()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3A%3AattachLoad/7.x), called from `NodeController::attachLoad()`, since `DrupalDefaultEntityController` is the parent class of `NodeController`; apart from field-related hooks, its code only invokes [`hook_entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_load/7.x) and `hook_TYPE_load()` which, for node entities, is `hook_node_load()`.

```
  // Attach fields.
  if ($this->entityInfo['fieldable']) {
    if ($revision_id) {
      field_attach_load_revision($this->entityType, $queried_entities);
    }
    else {
      field_attach_load($this->entityType, $queried_entities);
    }
  }

  // Call hook_entity_load().
  foreach (module_implements('entity_load') as $module) {
    $function = $module . '_entity_load';
    $function($queried_entities, $this->entityType);
  }
  // Call hook_TYPE_load(). The first argument for hook_TYPE_load() are
  // always the queried entities, followed by additional arguments set in
  // $this->hookLoadArguments.
  $args = array_merge(array($queried_entities), $this->hookLoadArguments);
  foreach (module_implements($this->entityInfo['load hook']) as $module) {
    call_user_func_array($module . '_' . $this->entityInfo['load hook'], $args);
  }
```